# Android Night Mode without CarModeEnabled

Tags: android-layout, android

So I made separate xmls for night mode and kept them in `layout-night`.

Then I switch to night mode:

```
UiModeManager uiManager = (UiModeManager) getSystemService(Context.UI_MODE_SERVICE);
    if (nightMode) {
        uiManager.enableCarMode(0);
        uiManager.setNightMode(UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    } else {
        uiManager.disableCarMode(0);
        uiManager.setNightMode(UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
    }
```

Is it possible  to set night mode without enabling car mode?

or for that matter possible to use `layout-night, values-night etc` folders without using `setNightMode()`?

Answer (score 3):

With 23.2.0(and higher) appcompat library it is possible with:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode
```

[Here](http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/android-daynight-theme-example-using-appcompat-v23-2/) you will find example.

Comment: @Mateusz Pryczkowski the link redirects to an unrelated site.  Please correct it or delete it.

Answer (score 2):

NO, According to docs setNightMode() `"Changes to the night mode are only effective when the car or desk mode is enabled on a device."`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiModeManager.html#setNightMode(int)

Check : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23123791/28557