# Activity Background change dynamic

Tags: android

I have just started developing an android weather app and I was wondering how to change activity background automatically. For example, in daytime it should show day time or in the night it should show night photos.

[This is the app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonymobile.xperiaweather&hl=en) of Sony which has a feature (mentioned above)

Check the screenshots.

Comment: There's no automatic. What's wrong in checking your requirements `if(something)` and changing the background with the normal Java calls`getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);` ?

Comment: night mode in layout. check its tutorial. it may help u.

Comment: Budius,I tried,but that din't slove the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay Credit goes to SteD;so for you check this(beginner's guide) 
Follow this
//set an ID for Relative Layout in content_main.xml(Android Studio)

```
 RelativeLayout rlayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rlayout); 
if(something){Drawable drawble=getResource().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_image);rlayout.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);}
```

//If it works,destroy the upvote

Answer (score 0):

The only automatic way is the newly released ([Day/Night theme for android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001551/day-night-theme-for-android-app))

For finer control you check the condition yourself and call the normal Java methods, like this:

```
if(something) {
   getWindow()
      .setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.image));
}
```

of if you don't care about the newly introduced context themed styling, you just call the deprecated method (which will keep working without issues for all the foreseeable future)

```
if(something) {
   getWindow()
       .setBackgroundDrawable(
              getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image));
}
```

Comment: Not Success :/ Thanks :) although