# Day and night mode in the android

Tags: android, webview

One of my work needs the switching between the day and night mode.
It has a webview which will load some HTML contents Via an HTML string. There should be two options in the menu for the day and night mode. how can i make it possible? If it move towards the next page it also provide an option to mode change.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13302317/how-to-switch-between-night-mode-and-day-mode-themes-on-android

Comment: thank u..  but i would like to know how these can be implemented by making changes in the html styles, without changing the style.xml. if i write an html style, is it possible to access that from the java class

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be to use a TextView and Html.fromHTML - depends a bit on your content if you are OK with the more limited feature-set - but day/night support would be easier this way.